# Method Color(int RGB) seems to be unknown

Tags: java, colors, 2d, rgb

```
    public class Object2D
/**
 * A TwoD_Object contains two ints resembling its width and height,
 * and a Color-Array constructed by them. That Array, contains the
 * information about every possible point that could be used in the
 * boundaries, set by int width and int height.
**/
{
int width;
int height;
Color PointInformation[][];
public void convertImageTo2DObject(BufferedImage image) {
      this.width = image.getWidth();
      this.height = image.getHeight();
      this.PointInformation = new Color[width][height];

  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
     for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        this.PointInformation[row][col] = Color(image.getRGB(col, row));
     }
  }

 }
```

I am kind of writing a class, that symbolizes a 2D-Object. Each object has an height and an width attribute and an twodimensional-color-Array of the size [width][height] that practically contains the colour of each possible point within the boundaries set by width and height.
Until now I wrote some methods, correctly drawing simple things like a point or a line, into an Object but now I want to translate a picture into my specification of a 2d-Object.

To do this, at first the height and width of the importet BufferedImage is calculated,

```
this.width = image.getWidth();
this.height = image.getHeight();
```

followed by a recreation of the PointInformation of the Object, that the image is copied onto.

```
 this.PointInformation = new Color[width][height];
```

Now two for-loops run over any pixel in the importet picture,

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
 for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
```

and theoretically asign the RGB-value of each pixel, converted to a color, into the right spot in the objects PointInformation.

```
this.PointInformation[row][col] = Color(image.getRGB(col, row));
 }
```

}

Now the problem here is, that the compiler in Netbeans tells me:

```
Cannot find symbol  
 symbol: method Color(int)  
 location: class Object2D
```

So it somehow has a problem with this line:

```
this.PointInformation = new Color[width][height];
```

But I don't understand what's the problem! I already did

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
```

(even though you don't see it here), and I even tried

```
import java.awt.*;
```

but it also did't work and still told me that it didn't know that method.

**I would really appreciate it, if you could tell me what I did wrong!
Thanks!**

Comment: You forgot the new in front of Color.

Comment: Strange. I thought I had already thanked the guy before you, but now his answer is kind of away o.O. Well, then I thank you^^-Thanks :D